# Separator line not showing full width in iPad

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview

Separator line not showing full width in iPad but it was set full width for iPhone devices after using these lines.

```
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

I've done all this via programmatically. Here is my code
[image]

Comment: why you are not tried in `Attribute Inspector`

Comment: Can you post more details about how the TableView and the Cells are set up?

Comment: Set it for table, not for a specific cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly changed in your Attribute Inspector change separator Inset --> custom and set left --> 0

[image: TableViewAttributesInspector]

and in your cell class also change the layout margin

[image: TableViewCellSizeInspector]

**Update**

> if want to remove the separator inset from all cells, you need to do two things. First, add these two lines of code to your table view controller's **viewDidLoad()** method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.layoutMargins = .zero
    tableView.separatorInset = .zero
}
```

> Now look for you **cellForRowAt** method and add this:

```
cell.layoutMargins = .zero
```

Comment: could please tell me how to do this by programmatically!

Comment: i've tried all those things but still i didn't get that. 
But its working perfectly in mobile devices

Comment: @KarthikeyanBose - what you modified

Comment: @KarthikeyanBose - ok

Answer (score 2):

The placeholder cells were not extending full width when I was programatically creating the UITableView. After trawling through all the possible methods, I discovered this.

```
tableview.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
```

I set this after setting the `contentInset = .zero` and the `layoutMargins = .zero`

Hopefully this helps other people in the same position.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Attribute Inspector to set the separator inset.

[image]

Change the Left value from 15 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding custom separator insets in tableview from the storyboard or the xib shown in the below image.
[image]

This will definitely work.